# Hermite-Hadamard's integral inequality for improper integrals

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis, improper-integrals

Let's say that $f(x)$ convex in the interval $[b,\infty)$, write the improper integral

$$\int_b^\infty f(x) dx.$$

Do Hermite-Hadamard's integral inequalities holds for this improper integral? Is there a proof this?

**Hermite-Hadamard integral inequalities:** Let $f(x)$ be a convex function in the interval $[a,c]$, then we have

$$f\left(\frac{a+c}{2}\right)(c-a) \leq \int_a^c f(x)dx \leq \frac{f(a)+f(c)}{2}(c-a).$$

Comment: Would you mind to write the inequality that you need explicitly?

Comment: @RobertZ of course, I apologize for my question's incompetence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f(x)$ is a convex function, for any $M>b$ and any $N\in\mathbb{N}^+$ we have
$$ \int_{b}^{M}f(x)\,dx \leq \frac{f(b)+f(M)}{2}+\frac{M-b}{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}f\left(b+\frac{k}{N}(M-b)\right) $$
by the standard version of the Hermite-Hadamard inequality. If $f(x)$ is convex and integrable over $[b,+\infty)$, then $\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=0$. By picking $M$ as $b+N$ we get
$$ \int_{b}^{b+N}f(x)\,dx \leq \frac{f(b)+f(b+N)}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}f\left(b+k\right) $$
and we may simply consider the limit of both sides as $N\to +\infty$ to be able to state
$$ \int_{b}^{+\infty}f(x)\,dx \leq \frac{f(b)}{2}+\sum_{k\geq 1}f(b+k).$$
So, long story short: *yes, it holds*.

Comment: Thank you very much! But I've one more question, how can I give an upper bound for $$\int_x^\infty x^2 dx $$ using your bound? ( This question may seem very stupid, but I prefer learning to stupidity.)

Comment: $x^2$ is not integrable over a left neighbourhood of $+\infty$.

Comment: Then let's say $1/x$ instead of $x^2$.

Comment: @BrightChancellor: same issue. But you can state that $$\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{x^2}\leq \frac{1}{2}+\sum_{k\geq 2}\frac{1}{k^2}, $$ for instance.

Comment: :) Thanks for expending your valuable time to answer my questions. You are a hero :)